# Predicting V8's Math.random() truncated outputs

Tags: javascript, python, random, web-applications, exploit

I'm doing a research & working around `Math.random()` like a month ago.
`Math.random()` uses **XORSHIFT128+**, so, if we can get the state of the PRNG, it'll be easy to predict future outputs.

It is public knowledge that **`Math.random()` isn't a CSPRNG**, quoting Mozilla's JS References :

> Note: `Math.random()` does not provide cryptographically secure random numbers. Do not use them for anything related to security.

Anyways, we all know we can **guess `Math.random()` future outputs by getting 3-4 consecutive outputs.**

Here's a github repo about that ->
https://github.com/PwnFunction/v8-randomness-predictor/tree/main

[And here's another repo about the same topic (This even doesn't need consecutive outputs)](https://github.com/XMPPwocky/nodebeefcl)

At this point, everything is very nice, but when we come to the **Practical & Real world aspects**, the things get really hard.
In a practical scenario, the apps don't leak raw `Math.random()` outputs, right?

Let's imagine we have a NodeJS back-end that generates "random" numbers in a specific range with **this function** :

```
function RandomInt(min, max) {
    let res = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    return res;
}
```

After defining that function, let's suppose **the server uses that function like this** and retrieves the data to the client :

```
//Let's generate some random values in different ranges
var randomValuesTest = {
    randomVal1:RandomInt(250,300),  
    randomVal2:RandomInt(0,900),
    randomVal3:RandomInt(300,500),  
    randomVal4:RandomInt(0,800),    
    randomVal5:RandomInt(500,900),  
    randomVal6:RandomInt(0,800),    
    randomVal7:RandomInt(0,900) 
};

return randomValuesTest;
```

[After googling three consecutive days, I just reached a guy that made a work-around for this using Python and Z3](https://github.com/d0nutptr/v8_rand_buster)

I have zero Python knowledge. I tried to adapt the code but I haven't achieved it. So i come with a **variety of questions and problems**:

How can I adapt this script to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It is a pure programming question and that's why it is off-topic on Security SE.

Comment: @mentallurg: I don't think it's a pure programming problem, but it was posted yesterday to much confusion, then deleted, and now reposted again today with almost the exact same language so there seems little hope of clarification. My guess is that it's about recovery of the RNG state from a small number of transformed outputs, which is a common cryptanalysis problem.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: 1) If the question was about cryptography, program codes would be not needed. 2) The OP says: *"I have zero Python knowledge, i tried to adapt the code but i haven't achieved it."* - To me it is a pure programming question.